# If L is accepted by some deterministic PDA then L has the prefix property.

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar, pushdown-automata

The question is from Ullaman and Hopcroft Automata theory book.

A Language is said to have prefix property if for all words in L, no proper prefix of any of those words exist in L. Prove that if L is accepted by some deterministic PDA then L has the prefix property.